# Set same font in letter as in moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv, scrlttr2

I created i cv using the package `moderncv`. I also would like to create a letter. So far i used `scrlttr2` package, but it uses a different font than `moderncv`, so it looks inconsistent. So my question is how do i set the same font.

Comment: If i remember correctly the moderncv template itself has latex code to typeset the covering letter in the last page. you can uncomment them when you need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, a combination of the two answers given will give the desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

% ---- beginning of relevant part
\usepackage{lmodern}% Latin Modern typeface (font)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% T1 font encoding for high quality font output

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% Latin Modern's sans serif font family as default
% ---- end of relevant part

\usepackage[english]{babel}% needed for scrlttr2

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The font size doesn't really matter, but you could change it with an option to `\documentclass`.

---

Here's what's happening in `moderncv.cls`:

l. 53ff:

```
% font type options
\DeclareOption{sans}{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}
\DeclareOption{roman}{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}}
```

l. 61f:

```
% execute default options
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,11pt,sans,final}
```

l. 85ff:

```
% automatic loading of latin modern fonts if present on the system
\IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}
  {\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}\RequirePackage{lmodern}}
  {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the lmodern Font, which is the standard in moderncv (`moderncv.cls`, line 86)

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: arg, that's what I wanted... seems I missed the button.

Answer (score 1):

In moderncv class I found the standard font sans 11pt

You can use that with

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\input{size11.clo}
```