# Problem with same font in scrltt2 and moderncv

Tags: moderncv, letters

I work with `TeXShop 3.58`. According to [Set same font in letter as in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61282/set-same-font-in-letter-as-in-moderncv) and [Adjust the font of scrlttr2 to the serif font of moderncv](http://Adjust%20the%20font%20of%20scrlttr2%20to%20the%20serif%20font%20of%20moderncv) you get the same font in `moderncv` and `scrlttr2` when you use the `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in `moderncv`.

To my eye the important word "Wanderlust" in the two MWE of doncherrys answer to [Adjust the font of scrlttr2 to the serif font of moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149763/adjust-the-font-of-scrlttr2-to-the-serif-font-of-moderncv) do not look identical. The left one (`moderncv`) looks slightly thicker than the right one (`scrlttr2`):

[image]

**moderncv** MWE of doncherry (`banking` instead of `casual`)

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking} %Philip changed to banking instead of casual
\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\end{document}
```

**scrlttr2** MWE of doncherry

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Wanderlust
\end{document}
```

**My question**: Why is it? And how can I make them look exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the "banking" stylefile (see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv ) one sees that it actually uses Pagella ( http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/texgyrepagella/ )

so the solution is simple: change `lmodern` to `tgpagella`

edit: stupid typo removed

Comment: Thank you: It is working. As I prefer the `lmodern` typo, I would like to ask if it would be possible to change the `moderncv` rather than the `scrlttr2` typo.

Comment: @Philip simply load `lmodern` sufficiently late (i.e. after setting styles etc.), alternatively: copy the style you want (banking)  change the font and store it locally as banking2 or whatever and use that style